# Find the value of the CDF $f(x)$ for 3 < x < 4

Tags: probability

The probability mass function for a descrete random variable X is given by $p(x) = cx, x = 1,2...7$

Find the value of the cdf $f(x)$ for $3 \leq x <4$

So I solved for $c$ by doing the following:

$$c(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7) = 1$$

$$c = \frac{1}{28}$$

But I am not sure how to find the value of the cdf $f(x)$ for  $3 \leq x <4$

Could someone please show me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally the cdf for any RV $X$is $F_X(x) = P(X \leq x)$.

So, $P(X \le 1) = c(1) = \frac{1}{28}$

$P(X \le 2) = c(1+2) = \frac{3}{28}$

$P(X \le 3) = c(1+2+3) = \frac{6}{28}$

$P(X \le 4) = c(1+2+3+4) = \frac{10}{28}$

and so on... so the required cdf in $3 \le x < 4 = \frac{6}{28}$

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For $3 \leq x < 4$, $f(x) = P(X < 4) = P(X \leq 3) = \frac{1}{28} (1+2+3)$